# Does using Javascript to lazy-load images retain the benefits of HTTP2?

Tags: javascript, image, lazy-loading, http2, multiplexing

I'm using HTTP2 to load all images on my website, and in several places I'm also using lazy-loading with a jQuery plugin i.e. loading images only when they enter the viewport.

My question is, does using Javascript to load images in this way negate the benefits of HTTP2? Rather than loading many images at once in parallel, they are loaded one-by-one, or a few at a time, which feels like a step back to HTTP1. Does the browser still use multiplexing when loading resources via JS?

Comment: What benefit do you believe you are getting from using JS to lazy load your images now?  There's rarely a good reason to do this.  Browsers are pretty good at prioritizing content.

Comment: Lazy loading it still useful, more to do with bandwidth, and why would you think the browser would stop using multiplexing when using javascript?  If the lazy loader is Async, I see no reason for any loss of performance.

Comment: @Brad I'm not sure that's true, since browsers have to wait to download all images before running any JS that follows them.

Comment: @Keith How can I tell if it's asynchronous?

Comment: If you have a lazy loading script, I'd be very surprised if it wasn't asynchronous, and any synchronous javascript is generally frowned upon nowadays.  The chances are a lazy loading script is just setting the src attribute of the image, as such this would be async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter to the browser whether you load resources or images via HTML tags (like `<img>`) or via Javascript (XHR or fetch API). It will still choose the protocol (HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2) depending on the capabilities of the server and not based on the way you use to request the resource.

That means also for loading anything via Javascript you will use HTTP/2 and multiplexing if the server supports it. And of course you take advantage from HTTP/2 features like only having to create a single TCP connection and header compression. However if your library only makes a single request at a time it might not utilize HTTP/2 to it's full potential as only a single HTTP/2 stream will be utilized then. In this case it might make sense to examine whether the library can be configured to load a number of parallel resources at once.

Comment: What is the time tcp connection still open , is it connection still opened until browser closed?

Comment: That isn't specified and can be decided by each browser implementation individually. I would guess they keep it alive for some amount of time to accommodate follow-up requests and Javascript, but then close it.